# Set UINavigationBar's background image

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar, appearance, tint

I have this piece of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-mid.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

It works If I try to set the TintColor to red (in the commented line of code), but If i try to set a background image it doesn't work!
Yes, I have the "bar-mid.png" image in "Supporting Files > Images".
I use storyboard.
This is the result:

[image]

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that it is being called within the "if" statement?

Comment: Presumably you've also tried using bar-mid.png elsewhere in the app just to rule that out?

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why, but I changed the name of the two images in "greenNavigation.png" and "greenNavigation@2x.png" , I changed `[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-mid.png"`] in `[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenNavigation.png"]` and now it works.
Someone know why?

Comment: perhaps it was not part of the target before? or you just needed a clean, so the file gets copied again..

Comment: No, it was part of the target before. I tried also with a clean build but nothing... then, I changed the name and boom, it works.

Comment: I'd suspect as jaydee3 - but also possibility of older duplicates. Anyway - glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me as well.
i delete image from xcode with "remove from hard disk" option.
save for web from photoshop again.
copy to xcode with "copy image to solution folder" option.
then voila. it works.
i know, not much of an explanation but it works sometimes.
maybe it does not like image encoding or something.